# Checking data types in C++ using ifstream

Tags: c++, types, ifstream

I'm trying to learn how to upload and read files using ifstream in C++ (fairly new to programming so I'm trying to start simple). As my example file, I have this in a text file:

```
3
1
2
```

and this in the main file:

```
int num;
ifstream infile;
infile.open(filename,ios::in);
infile>>num;
cout<<num<<endl;
```

so if I replace the first line in my text file:

```
k
1
2
```

I want my program to check that the first entry in my file is of type int and then exit out and give me an error if it is not. Instead, I always get 0 as the output. What can I do check for this possible error?

Comment: You can try `file.goog()` or `file.bad()`. check [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/good/) for detail

Comment: Excellent, it seems to be working the way I want it to now. What a "good" function. Thank you and I'll be sure to bookmark this website

Answer (score 1):

This is how it should be done. Checking `good()` is not recommended:

```
while (infile >> num)
{
    std::cout << num << std::endl;
}

if (infile.fail() && !infile.eof())
{
    std::cout << "Invalid number";
}
```